# problema con el Sorting en un QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Estoy armando una tabla con `QTableWidget` en **`PyQt5`**..

Le setié el `sortingEnabled` a `True`, pero el problema es que no ordena bien los números.

Por ejemplo, si tengo 20, 201 y 30, los ordena de la siguiente manera:

```
descendente: 30, 201, 20

ascendente: 20, 201, 30
```

Codigo:

```
    self.tabla = QTableWidget()
    self.tabla.setColumnCount(6)
    self.tabla.setRowCount(1)
    self.tabla.setShowGrid(True)
    self.tabla.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Venta','Marca','Plataforma','Cantidad','Valor','Fecha'))
    self.tabla.setStyleSheet('background-color:#d6f9ff; border-radius: 20px; border: 2px solid gray;')
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.tabla.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(5, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.tabla.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    self.tabla.setEditTriggers(self.tabla.NoEditTriggers)
    self.tabla.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tabla.verticalHeader().hide()
    layout.addWidget(self.tabla,2,0,1,10)

    check_table()
    row_count = 1
    for index, row in enumerate(get_all_ventas()):
        self.tabla.setRowCount(row_count)
        for index2, attr in enumerate(row):
            self.tabla.setItem(index,index2,QTableWidgetItem(str(attr)))
        row_count += 1
```

Para mi el problema es que en realidad los números son `strings`, el tema es que si yo los agrego a la tabla como `int`, la tabla no los muestra..
¿Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extraído de [SO en Ingés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938459/sorting-in-pyqt-tablewidget)

En la línea que insertas los `QTableWidgetItem`:
`self.tabla.setItem(index,index2,QTableWidgetItem(str(attr)))`

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
qtwi = QTableWidgetItem()
qtwi.setData(Qt.EditRole, QVariant(index2))
self.tabla.setItem(index, index2, qtwi)
```

Tal y como comentas el problema reside en que al añadir el elemento como un `string` lo va a tratar como tal, para poder tratarlo como un dato tienes que usar el `setData`.